# JavaScript - Press Space when page finished loading

Tags: javascript

How do I trigger the page to press Space when it has finished loading?

I've tried:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $.keypress(e.keyCode(32));
});
```

Comment: What should happen when space is pressed? What should receive the keypress?

Comment: Are you trying to get to a certain spot on a page or just fire a key?  Because if it's the latter, you should use named anchors instead because they are more reliable and mobile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, not 100% sure why you'd want to do this, but ignoring that, triggering stuff like this always seems to be unreliable, but this is the best way:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    var e = $.Event("keydown");
    e.which = 32; // space key code value
    $(this).trigger(e);
});
```

But there's probably better ways to trigger whatever you want to do after the space is hit.